# PRNG based on statistical data (Python)

Tags: python, statistics

I want to generate random numbers based on statistics. I have statistics on Internet traffic for people of different age categories (12-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55+, total number and percentage).

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Lpl.png) and [Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alosa.png).

Can I use Python to generate random numbers (age) based on these statistics?

Comment: Yes, but the wording of your question indicates potential misunderstanding.  The normal path is to fit a distribution to your data.  PRNGs usually generate values uniformly distributed over the set of integers or uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.  The latter can be converted to pretty much any distribution you like (such as the one you fit to your data) by any of a wide variety of transformation methods.  More specific answers would require info about the target distribution.  As written, your question is too broad.

Comment: I tried to solve it this way:

`range_age = [list(range(12, 18)), list(range(18, 25)), list(range(25, 35)), list(range(35, 45)), list(range(45, 55)), list(range(55, 65))]`

`age = random.choice(
   np.random.choice(range_age,
                    p=[0.179, 0.257, 0.37, 0.109, 0.037, 0.048]))`